# Redmine Icalendar export issue in mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, icalendar, bitnami

I am facing some issues when try to install following plugin in mac os. 
It is working fine in linux as well as in windows. 
https://github.com/thegcat/redmine_ical

**Steps I followed:**

After copying plugin files in vendor/plugin folder. Redmine stops working and shows "We're sorry but something went wrong" error message.

I am using bitnami-redmine-1.4.7-2-osx-x86_64-installer.dmg and when I remove Gemfile and require dispatcher from init.rb It starts running but doesn't show Ical on calendar page.

Comment: log tail will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After copying plugin file we need to run "bundle install" command from terminal.

In bitnami stack redmine after copying plugin file,

1) $cd install dir
2) $./use_redmine
3) $bash: cd root_dir
4) bundle install

This will work .

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, but did help me one step.

I had to do the following to make it work succesfully:

```
cd installdir/apps/redmine/htdocs
bundle install --without development test postgresql sqlite --no-deployment
bundle install --without development test postgresql sqlite --deployment
ruby bin/rake redmine:plugins RAILS_ENV=production
```

This all in addition to (or actually from within) using the "use_redmine" bash from the install dir.

I've opted to go for the other ical plugin, that didn't require the patchfiles (https://github.com/buschmais/redmics)

https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/redmine/#how-to-install-the-redmine-agile-plugin